# Saved QGIS Project is empty!

Tags: qgis

I worked a complete night in a project involving a research of my group. When I tried to open it today, it's blank, there are no layers at all. As you can see in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMaVc.jpg) the thumbnail in the home screen of the projects (it's the top one) looks normal, but when I open it, it's blank.

Can you open the .qgz project at this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b868Cn1-bV3Yr_DROybfGAclOIoo1iK4/view?usp=sharing), and maybe check its integrity and get a hint of what could be wrong?

I'm working with QGIS 3.2 in a Windows 10 64 bits. All my other projects are opening just fine.

Comment: If your case is related to this reported [bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20292), then renaming your project may help. Good luck!

Comment: Indeed that was the case, thank you! Renaming didn't work, but I just installed QGIS 3.6 Noosa and the original project opened without issues, for safety I saved it with a new name. Problem solved.

Comment: If you post this as answer and mark it as solved it would help others as well